# Grafana / PromQL query to chart a value per hour in a bar chart

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a database which I monitor using the oracle db exporter, scraped by Prometheus in a 60 seconds interval.
Next to the database metrics like tablespace filling degree etc. I would like to present a couple of metrics from my application.

Now I would like to have a bar chart in Grafana which displays the result of a select using a "group By" in SQL, in my case the number of events per hour.

The metric looks like this

```
target_full_counter{timeBase="2023-12-11 13"} 8
target_full_counter{timeBase="2023-12-11 14"} 3
```

The timeBase label contains the hour (including day).
Every value will appear every minute in that time series and will vanish one day
when the data from the database is deleted. (Could also just select the value for the last 36 hours or so from the database)

Now I would like to have these values charted in a bar chart for every hour.
The problem is only that I get 60 bars drawn for every hour.
In Grafana I set the query format to Table and use a transformation to use the timeBase label as the time value.

[Bar chart with multiple values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60YQB.png)

I can get around that by setting the minStep in Grafana to 1h, but then it will not give me the value for the current hour.
And every attempt I made with different PromQL I fail to basically get the "last value" for each "timeBase"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach of "group by hour" stored in Prometheus is incorrect:

- time related data should **not** be stored in labels with rare exceptions (which this case is not),
- if you already have query providing raw data as you need it, you should consider skipping Prometheus, and querying this data directly by Grafana.

If you cannot use [Oracle Data Source](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-oracle-datasource/)<sup>*</sup>, and intend on keeping Prometheus as a source of data I recommend you changing your approach:
Instead of exporting per-hour values export full counter over current day. Then, when querying data from Prometheus use it's function [`increase`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase) to calculate per-hour change (it will also internally take care of counter resets on midnights).

```
increase(target_full_counter [1h])
```

Additionally, don't forget to set *Min step* in query options of the panel to `1h`, to produce one "bar" in the one hour<sup>**</sup>.

---

Finally, if you intend on creating custom metrics, please refer [Best practices in metric and label naming](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/naming/).

---

<sup>*</sup> : it requires premium version of Grafana. Alternatively, you probably could take existing oss plugin for other RDBMS, for example [MySQL one](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/tree/main/public/app/plugins/datasource/mysql), and modify it to work with Oracle.
<sup>**</sup> : Alternatively, to get value over last hour, you might wrap your query into `avg_over_time( <your_query_here>  [1h:1h])` instead of *Min step* option. This might or might not work for different panels and configurations of said panels.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. The idea with the daily resetting counter worked for me.
To include the current hour I found the solution to add an offset like that:

`increase(target_full_counter [1h] offset -1h)`

I did not have a look into Grafana Enterprise, maybe I will give it a try to modify an existing SQL plugin to directly connect to the database. Thanks for that hint as well.